# My 3yr son wont tell me when he needs to go to the bathroom

Tags: pre-schooler, potty-training

When my son was two he started letting me know when he wanted to go to the potty. He then started nursery and went back to old ways of not letting me know.

He's now three and I've taken him out of diapers however he still wont go. He will sit on the toilet but wont go until we've pulled his pants up.

How can I encourage him to (1) Tell us when he needs to us the bathroom and (2) Go to the bathroom when he IS sitting on the toilet.

Comment: This question seems to be similar and may have some good advice: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/10778/my-3-years-old-doesnt-tell-me-when-he-needs-to-use-the-bathroom?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Tell you will reward him with something (doesn't have to something big), for ever time he tells you that he needs to go to the toilet or sits on the toilet.